# Pass parameters through link_to(r) do... end

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, url-parameters

My code loops through several images. Each image is a link and what I want is to pass the same url parameter in those links.

```
<% @render.each_slice(2) do |renders| %>
        <div class="row">
            <% renders.each do |r| %>           
                <%= link_to(r) do %>
                    <div class="col-md-6" align="center" style="margin-bottom: 5em; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <%= image_tag(r.image) %>               
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>           
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

I have tried link_to(r, :link => 'portafolio') in a lot of ways.

routes.rb is like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see    http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
root 'pages#main'
get 'index/' => 'pages#index'
get 'index/see' => 'pages#see'
get 'index/see/:id' => 'pages#show', as: :render
end
```

Comment: So, what exactly returns you the url? `r`, `r.image` or what?

Comment: Its the path to each image which is managed by the def show

Comment: What kind of path it is, that it has `image` method?

Comment: I added my file routes.rb to the question, there you can see the path

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: There you can see the path 'index/see/:id' is the kind of path that redirects you to the id of the image you click

Comment: It is also an object as you can see '@render' turns into renders and renders into r. I mean the link is working without any trouble, i just can't find the way to pass more parameters @sergio

Comment: Sure you can. Just make `r` respond to `image`. Apparently, it does not to that. Or does, but returns empty string or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the path and use r to specify the id

```
<%= link_to render_path(r, link: :portafolio, parameter: :value) do %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass a block on a `link_to` helper you must specify the path, you're just passing `r`, but what's that value? what does it print?

You could try specifying the path, and inside as params the `r` value:

```
<%= link_to some_path(parameter: value_for_r) do %>
  <!-- The content wrapped in the link_to -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: r is actually a path, is the path to each image managed by the function show in the controller. Since the path for each image is different I need to use it this way

Comment: So you can use `r(some_parameter: some_value)` if `r` is the path, and is defined in order to expect a parameter.

Comment: I get an error when i try it that way. link_to r(link: => "portafolio")

Comment: As you've defined `pages#show` you need to pass a parameter called `id`, which error are you getting?, also don't use the fat arrow, try `r(id: some_id)`, `some_id` because is what the route is expecting for.

Comment: Undefined method 'r', yes i know, the id passes as a parameter without any trouble, the problem is that i need to pass more parameters which i don't know how. I added the routes.rb file to the question so that you can se the path every image follows depending on their id.

Comment: The link works perfectly but i can't pass more parameters to the url @sebastián

Comment: You can pass just one because you've defined just the `id` to be expected (: `'index/see/:id'`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want the url to look like this 'index/see/5?type=interior&link=portafolio'